# Send e-mails from DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database in which I hold the mail adress from all the users on my website. 
How can I send an e-mail to each of them?

I guess PHP is a little slow. I've tried a CGI script but it failed (it sent some e-mails then it got stuck xD).

Is there an "usuable" PHP only solution? I only have like 300users atm, but I want the script to work for like 10.000 users.

I've heard about SwiftMailer (or something like that) but I want to know if I can create my own script that can work.

Comment: Yes you can. Connect to the DB, get the email addresses, loop around them, use the mail() function. Simple.

Comment: "I guess PHP is a little slow" Guess again. :-) What are the exact problems you encounter? I've seen PHP applications send thousands of mails without a problem.

Comment: Sending 10000 (or possibly even just 300) emails at once will probably get you flagged as a spammer. [Read this](http://www.emailaddressmanager.com/email-marketing/bulk-email-software.html) before you go any further with this task.

Comment: One more thing, don't send the mails too quickly, as the mail account used to send emails maybe temporarily disabled, this happened to me using a gmail account.

Comment: I think looping through them and using mail() will exceed the maximum time excution (I'd have to change that). So the problem is that I can't "test" the program because I can't know if the e-mails reach their destination... It's an "one shot" :D

Answer (score 3):

Don't recreate the wheel. SwiftMailer is easy to use, extensible, and very customizable. It also has considerations for throttling and antiflooding.

Comment: I'll try to use that but the documentation seems preatty big... :(

Comment: It's not that bad; on the documentation page there's step by step instructions with code samples on how to do pretty much anything you'd ever want to.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a timeout issue (mail() function is really slow) I usually use ajax to have the server do a small slice (say 10 rows) at a time. That also gives you feedback about how far along it is in processing the whole file. Each subsequent ajax call tells the server what line to start on, it does 10 sends back a success/fail to the browser/javascript, which sends another ajax request to do another 10, repeat.

Comment: Actually this is a good idea :). This may be the solution, thanks :D